# Custom increments in slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-slider

i want to increase the value of radius like `0 miles,1 miles,2 miles,3 miles,4 miles,5 miles,10 miles,15 miles,20 miles,30 miles,50 miles` in slider in flutter ?
Any suggestion how to do it ?
This is my code

```
min: 0,
max: 50,
divisions: 50,
value: _value,
onChanged: (value) {
  setState(() {
    _value = value;
    print(_value);
  });
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Using String interpolation,

```
int _value;
```

then, add 'miles' wherever you need "15 miles,20 miles, etc".
eg,

```
Text('$value Miles'),
```

UPDATE

Make a function to return "int" number of division-
Make 2 variables, minn amd maxn, (global)

```
updateDiv({int min,int max}){
/* Your condition hoes here
//If(min==5&&max==8){

return min(//your condition)

elseif{
}
*/
```

in your slider

```
min:minn,
max:maxn,
division:updateDiv(min: minn, max:maxn),
```

Comment: use case :
min : 0
max : 50
now i want to increment its value 
for 0 - 5 miles :- value should be increased by 1(1,2,3,4,5)
for 5 - 20 :- value should increase by 5(5,10,15,20)
for 20 -30 :- value should increase by 10(20,30)
for 30-50 :- value should increase by 20(30-50)
i cannot find a way to dynamically change its division

Comment: If you want to achieve that. Make a function which accepts min and max numbers, and returns a "int" division, based on the conditions you specified above. Call that function in when initialising the division, and pass min and max value. I'm updating my answer, please check.